# How to work with multiple external css file in same node js(without express) project?

Tags: node.js

**i want to load style.css  for home and about.css for about page**
*but it only load the style.css for all pages. the css from about page is not working*

```
const http = require('http')

const { readFileSync } = require('fs')

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/') {
    let data = readFileSync('./home.html')

    res.write(data)
    res.end()
  }else if (req.url === '/about') {
    let data = readFileSync('./about.html')

    res.write(data)
    res.end()
  }else if (req.url === '/fish.png'){
    const image = readFileSync('fish.png')
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'image/png' })
    
    res.write(image)
    res.end()
  } else if (req.url = '/style.css') {
    const css = readFileSync('./style.css')
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/css' })
    res.write(css)
    res.end()
  }else if (req.url = '/about.css') {
    const css = readFileSync('./about.css')
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/css' })
    res.write(css)
    res.end()
  }
  else {
    res.end('something is wrong with the server')
  }
})

server.listen(8080, () => console.log('server is running on 8080'))
```

***i want any solution without using express js***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use strict equality like what you have declared above.

```
req.url === '/style.css'
req.url === '/about.css'
```